# How does eating or drinking affect lateral flow tests using nasal swab only?

Tags: covid-19

With Covid testing in England (not sure about Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland) the free lateral flow kits have been in 2 forms.

### The first DHSC kits

[image: DHSC lateral flow test kits]

DHSC (Department of Health and Social Care) home lateral flow testing kits require both throat and nasal swabbing (see [this instruction booklet PDF](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1024894/COVID-19-self-test-throat-and-nose-instructions.pdf)).

### The new kits

For a while now, they changed the free kits to ACON Flowflex.

[image: ACON Flowflex Lateral Flow Covid Testing Kit]

These only require nasal swabbing (see [this instruction booklet PDF](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1030995/COVID-19-self-test-nose-only-instructions-acon-flowflex.pdf))

Both sets of instructions state that you must not eat or drink 30 minutes prior to conducting the test (Page 3 of both instruction booklets).

I can understand the possibility that eating or drinking before or during the test could affect the results if throat swabbing, but I can't find anything online why it would affect nasal swabbing.

How would eating or drinking affect the new nasal swab only testing?

Comment: Could be an attempt to prevent excess mucus/discharge from spicy food lowering sensitivity, but not sure. Best bet might be to contact manufacturer.